# Multilingual issue with wysywyg editors

Tags: php, tinymce, ckeditor, multilingual

I am using tinymce for my posts in the system and getting problem with accented charachters, now here is what happened on my side.

If I type french accented character lets say `à` my tiny mce converts it into `&agrave;` but I really do need to save this character `à` in my database rather than saving `&agrave;`.

I have also tried with ckEditor but the problem is same.

Can anyone tell me how to overcome this problem as I am on tight deadline and its really becoming a headache, it will be great if anyone can help.

Comment: TinyMCE will use some kind of `htmlspecialchars()`, try if you can find a way to disable that. :)

Comment: Have you tried unloading the related plugins? I think it's `specialchars` and `entities`. - http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.removePlugins

Answer (score 1):

ok I have solved it using php french accents array. Following function I have created.

```
    function replaceAccents($content)
    {
        //French Accent Array
        $arrFrenchAccent=array('À'=>'&Agrave;', 'à'=>'&agrave;', 'Á'=>'&Aacute;', 'á'=>'&aacute;', 'Â'=>'&Acirc;', 'â'=>'&acirc;', 'Ã'=>'&Atilde;', 'ã'=>'&atilde;', 'Ä'=>'&Auml;', 'ä'=>'&auml;', 'Å'=>'&Aring;', 'å'=>'&aring;', 'Æ'=>'&AElig;', 'æ'=>'&aelig;', 'Ç'=>'&Ccedil;', 'ç'=>'&ccedil;', 'Ð'=>'&ETH;', 'ð'=>'&eth;', 'È'=>'&Egrave;', 'è'=>'&egrave;', 'É'=>'&Eacute;', 'é'=>'&eacute;', 'Ê'=>'&Ecirc;', 'ê'=>'&ecirc;', 'Ë'=>'&Euml;', 'ë'=>'&euml;', 'Ì'=>'&Igrave;', 'ì'=>'&igrave;', 'Í'=>'&Iacute;', 'í'=>'&iacute;', 'Î'=>'&Icirc;', 'î'=>'&icirc;', 'Ï'=>'&Iuml;', 'ï'=>'&iuml;', 'Ñ'=>'&Ntilde;', 'ñ'=>'&ntilde;', 'Ò'=>'&Ograve;', 'ò'=>'&ograve;', 'Ó'=>'&Oacute;', 'ó'=>'&oacute;', 'Ô'=>'&Ocirc;', 'ô'=>'&ocirc;', 'Õ'=>'&Otilde;', 'õ'=>'&otilde;', 'Ö'=>'&Ouml;', 'ö'=>'&ouml;', 'Ø'=>'&Oslash;', 'ø'=>'&oslash;', 'Œ'=>'&OElig;', 'œ'=>'&oelig;', 'ß'=>'&szlig;', 'Þ'=>'&THORN;', 'þ'=>'&thorn;', 'Ù'=>'&Ugrave;', 'ù'=>'&ugrave;', 'Ú'=>'&Uacute;', 'ú'=>'&uacute;', 'Û'=>'&Ucirc;', 'û'=>'&ucirc;', 'Ü'=>'&Uuml;', 'ü'=>'&uuml;', 'Ý'=>'&Yacute;', 'ý'=>'&yacute;', 'Ÿ'=>'&Yuml;', 'ÿ'=>'&yuml;');     

        //Fliping arrays(keys and values) removing indexes using array_values.
        $originalFrench =   array_values(array_flip($arrFrenchAccent));
        //removing indexes using array_values.
        $arrFrenchAccent    =   array_values($arrFrenchAccent);
        //replacing e.g &Agrave; with À within the content
        $content    =   utf8_encode(str_replace($arrFrenchAccent,$originalFrench,$content));
        return $content;
    }
```

I hope it will help anyone who gets the same problem.

Regards,
Mustafa

Answer (score 0):

Check the tinymce parameter [entity_encoding.](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aentity_encoding)